# factor derivative

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

If Dy/Dx = -5sin(5x-3y)+(Dy/Dx(5-3))

Then how can: (1-3*sin(5x-3y))Dy/Dx = -5sin(5x-3y)

And so  the derivative is  -5sin(5x-3y) / (1-3sin(5x-3y))

How can the derivative dissapear , it's factored but still doesn't make sense to me.

From khanacademy .go check this video because it's confusing on the forum.

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-calculus/dc-chain/dc-implicit-diff-advanced/v/implicit-derivative-of-y-cos-5x-3y

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also, use MathJax (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: What do you mean that the derivative disappears? It's always there. What else is $\frac{dy}{dx}$? Which step in the movie is unclear?

Comment: i mean the 1 in: (1-3 * sin(5x-3y) ) * Dy/Dx, how can the derivative become 1. go on the site at end of video

Comment: The derivative is not one. If you have an expression like $\frac{dy}{dx}+3\frac{dy}{dx}$, you can write it as $(1+3)\frac{dy}{dx}=4\frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: ah now i think i got it by also kinda rewatching the video thanks